# Deep linking and multiple app instances in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, deep-linking

I added this intent filter in my manifest file, and the deep linking is working.

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data
     android:host="website.in"
     android:pathPrefix="/sometag/"
     android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

The problem is that through deep linking, my app is launching on top of current app. If I am in Gmail and I click a link, then my app is launching on top of Gmail.

If my app is already running in background and I click on a link in Gmail which redirects to my app, I have two instances of my app running at the same time.One in the background, and another on top of Gmail. I want to run only one instance of my app at a time, so it's not also on top of the current app (Gmail).

Refered this link but not working solutions :[Deep linking and multiple app instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884954/deep-linking-and-multiple-app-instances)

Answer (score 4):

Finally got solution for my problem added

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

in `Android Manifest` and override `onNewIntent`.and check whether existing instance is already created.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `launchMode` attribute of your Activity (depending on what you expect to happen).
[Documentation is here](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)