# Open the app when i click on validation link

Tags: android, firebase, validation

I have a validation system using firebase Email validation. when I clcik on validation link in the email,the link opens a web page. now I want to open my app when I click the link.
is it possible ? How can i do this?

Comment: see [How to launch app on click of url in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807300/how-to-launch-app-on-click-of-url-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep linking and multiple app instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884954/deep-linking-and-multiple-app-instances)

Comment: @Nigam Patro I try that link but not work for me.

Comment: @Manohar Reddy, after working according to your link. it not woking, and i got another problem after flow your link. the app icon is not showing in my mobile

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml